# REST - Nested resources and controllers & Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, controller, routes

I'm wondering what would be best practice in regards to RESTful design for controllers. So I've got a URL structure like below...

```
Route::get('/clients', 'ClientController@index');
Route::get('/clients/{client}', 'ClientController@show');
Route::get('/clients/{client}/{job}', 'JobController@show');
Route::get('/jobs/{job}', 'JobController@show');
```

Now in the controller for the third route, I need to do some checks to make sure that job belongs to that client, but I also to be able to look at a job independently of a client like in route 4. So what i'm wondering is the best way to split this logic up, should I...

1. Create a new method on the ClientController which handles fetching a job and making sure it belongs to that client.
2. Have two seperate methods on the JobController, one for fetching a job and one for fetching and checking it belongs to that client.
3. Create a new ClientJobsController, which handles any logic for when we need to relate jobs with clients.

Hope that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: This all looks standard rest but for clarity's sake I would definitely add the name of the resource before the ID. (I mean for the third route in your example).

eg. `Route::get('/clients/{$id}/jobs/{$id}'...`
Then `Route::get('/clients/{$id}/jobs/` could return all jobs for a client. -- also I'd probably relegate the check if a job belongs to a client to a middleware.

Comment: Quick suggestion: I suggest you to take a look at [this talk](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI) by Adam Wathan at Laracon 2017. It should give you an example on how to refactor your controllers/routes to adhere more to the REST standard and maybe clarify your doubts